# Loading screen using JavaScript changes nothing on a phone

Tags: javascript, html, loading

I have a simple question.
I'm trying to get ride of the blank page when I load a html page with 2 videos in it.
I searched for some solutions and the most popular I've found seems to be this one (With some css).

```html
  <script>
        // Wait for window load
        $(window).load(function() {
              // Animate loader off screen
              $(".TheDivClass").fadeOut("slow");;
        });
  </script>
```

But there is no noticeable difference when I load my website using my phone (on chrome or safari) and I was wondering why. It still loads in a blank page during at least 50 sec and then the loader icon shows up for 0.5 sec.

Should I put the link of the site to show what I mean?
It's a portfolio :)

https://velynns.netlify.com/

**The Solution :**

```html
            // Wait for window load
            $(window).load(function() {
                  // Animate loader off screen
                  $('#Video1').load('LoadVideo1.html');
                  $('#Video2').load('LoadVideo2.html');
                  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
            });
```

Where LoadVideo1 & LoadVideo2 contains the video tags.

Comment: 2 videos and a 50 second load time? I feel as though you have a bigger problem here

Comment: please share your link i cant understand what you want to make.

Comment: Here is the link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your videos must be causing delays on the loading of everything all together.
A better way to handle this situation might be to remove the videos all together from the website first, but keeping the empty div's to place the videos in after loading your page.

1 - Show the "page loading" animation
2 - After loading animation is showing, load the videos into the website
3 - Once the videos are loaded, then hide the page loading animation.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {  
    $('#movie-div').load('movie.html');
});
```

Do something like this to load the video into the empty div after the page is loaded up.